# QPainter error in GUI application

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt4

I'm trying to write a GUI that paints a graph onto it in C++. I am getting a list of errors, all of which say:
"QPainter::begin: Widget painting can onnly begin as a result of a paintEvent"
Nothing appears to be painting.

### main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFont>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include "skewNormal.h"
#include "ui.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Window w;
    #if defined(Q_OS_SYMBIAN)
    w.showMaximized();
    #else
    w.show();
    #endif
    return app.exec();
}
```

### ui.h

```
#ifndef UI_H_INCLUDED
#define UI_H_INCLUDED
#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>

class Window : public QWidget
{
    public:
    Window();

    void paintEvent ( QPaintEvent * event );
};



#endif // UI_H_INCLUDED
```

### ui.cpp

```
#ifndef GRAPHPN3670_H
#define GRAPHPN3670_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtGui/QAction>
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QPaintEvent>
#include <QtGui/QGraphicsView>
#include <QtGui/QHeaderView>
#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include <QtGui/QMenuBar>
#include <QtGui/QStatusBar>
#include <QtGui/QWidget>
#include <QtCore/QRect>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include "ui.h"
#include "skewNormal.h"

Window::Window()
{
    cout<<"Hello1";
}

void Window::paintEvent ( QPaintEvent * event ){
    cout<<"Hello from paint event";
    QPainter p(this);
    int xL = -width() / 2;
    int yL = 0;
    for(int x = -width() / 2; x < width() / 2; x++)
    {
        int y = getSkewNormal(0.5, x);
        p.drawLine(xL + width() / 2, height() - yL, x + width() / 2, height() - y);
        xL = x;
        yL = y;
    }
}

#endif // GRAPHPE3488_H
```

Comment: You set your application as console application ? without doing this the console won't print any message!

Comment: @LoSciamano How do I fix that??

Comment: You could do a lot to trim down your example, which would help us (and you) understand what's going on more easily.  For starters, a lot of those includes are unnecessary, and you could just use height() and width() directly instead of getWidth() and getHeight().  Also, (I hope) you don't need an include guard in `ui.cpp`.

Comment: More than anything, reduce all of the drawing code to a single QPainter::drawLine() call (or something similar) and get that working before you worry about any of your skew code.

Comment: Yeah, the skew code works. I've tested it separately. I'll remove it. I just wanted to have everything up there just in case. EDIT: Done! :D

Comment: No, I mean don't even call it.  Change your paintEvent to do nothing except draw a line from one corner of the widget to the opposite corner, and see if that works.

Comment: I tried adding a fill rectangle: http://pastie.org/private/vewpsv5mjmj2dkvdcbwva. It doesn't work.

Comment: The default brush (which you appear to be using) has the style `Qt::NoBrush`.

Comment: Awesome :D That makes a big black square in the corner, which is what it was supposed to do. Thanks! But now I need to figure out how to do the rest.

Comment: @Steve S Score! Thanks, works now. Case closed. Now I just have to work the math.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qpainter.html):

> Warning: When the paintdevice is a
>   widget, QPainter can only be used
>   inside a paintEvent() function or in a
>   function called by paintEvent(); that
>   is unless the
>   Qt::WA_PaintOutsidePaintEvent widget
>   attribute is set. On Mac OS X and
>   Windows, you can only paint in a
>   paintEvent() function regardless of
>   this attribute's setting.

Comment: Well, that fixes the error. It's still not drawing. Does the paintEvent fire automatically or does it need to be manually called? EDIT: yes, it does. I'll post up my code, one second. EDIT2: Posted

Comment: @Somanayr: It's automatic.  See http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#paintEvent

Comment: Ok, but it's still not painting :(
Did I do some settings wrong for the painting?

Comment: `setAttribute(Qt::WA_PaintOutsidePaintEvent, true);` solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're not doing widget painting correctly.

The proper thing way to do it is like this;

```
// Add this method to your widget class
virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * e)
{
   QPainter p(this);
   // Add all calls to p.drawPoint(), etc here
}
```

... and that is the only place you should be using QPainter.  Then, whenever you want your widget to repaint itself, call update() on your widget, and Qt will call paintEvent() for you shortly afterwards.

Comment: QPainter has no constructor QPainter(PaintEvent *e). You need to use this, a QWidgit which is a QPaintDevice. I've updated the OP with the fix

Comment: Oops -- that's what I get for writing code from memory.  I'll fix my post.

Answer (score 2):

You need to show the window

```
Window w;
w.show()
return app.exec();
```

Comment: Try removing the `show()` from the constructor and call it like @Martin is suggesting.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and noted that in the OP. The result is that the constructor and the rest of the main method are called after the window is closed

Comment: I put the updated source in the OP. I get a ton of errors, all saying "QPainter::begin: Widget painting can onnly begin as a result of a paintEvent"

Answer (score 2):

First, call `show()` as suggested by Martin Beckett. Second, you cannot call `paintEvent()` yourself. You need to override `paintEvent()` and do your drawing there. Please see the example I provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159830/how-to-send-qline-coordinate-to-a-qpainter-widget/6163547#6163547).

Comment: Can you take a look at the fix I provided, please? Instead of overriding paintEvent, I simply modified my draw method

Comment: That will not work. Running your program should demonstrate that. You cannot draw in the constructor of a widget.

Comment: Ok, let me try this again :) Not only can you not do the drawing in the constructor, you cannot do the drawing from any other location or method besides an override of paintEvent().

Comment: Yeah, someone else just explained that. I didn't understand that part. It works now, no error. But it doesn't paint :(. I've updated the OP with the changes.

Comment: Well, maybe you could do something simple in your paintEvent() like draw a line from 0,0 to 100,100 to rule out a problem with your geometry calculations. Maybe try setting the pen color too.

Comment: I tried both of those. The result is the same: a grey window. Here's the method: http://pastie.org/private/vewpsv5mjmj2dkvdcbwva. I don't see what's wrong with it, although I bet it's something really dumb. I know it's entering the method because of console output.